# What are the dimensions of the Mac Book Air 13" screen?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

Every spec I've seen shows the diagonal measurement of 13.3". I'm interested in the actual width and height of the screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To calculate the screen dimension given the diagonal measurement and the resolution:

The 13.3" MacBook has a 1400 x 900 resolution. Assuming square pixel this gives us

[image]

which we can solve for `x`

[image]

The resulting value of `x` needs to be multiplied with 1400 and 900 to give the screen dimensions, in this case 11.2" x 7.2".

Answer (score 2):

Well, based on the official [Apple specs](https://www.apple.com/macbook-air/specs/) the exterior dimensions of the 13” MacBook Air are 12.8” by 8.94”. But that is of course dimensions for the entire body of the MacBook Air and not just the screen (which is a bit smaller obviously).

I’ve actually got a 13” MacBook Air and a quick measure with a ruler gives me the dimensions of 11.375” by 7.125”.